# PreCommitPhase - Failed to Prepare: tcm:0-145378-66560 error: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Tags: content-delivery

I am deploying a transaction with a few binaries, pages and DCPs.  It spins for a very long time in the Commiting Deployment phase and then throws an error:

> Polling for notification for destination: HiyUWJm0W37fdhYGm+hltg== has
>   exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-145378-66560

The cd_deployer.log reveals the following:

> 2013-12-10 14:48:28,051 ERROR StorageManagerTransactionMonitor -
>   Rolling back a stale transaction: tcm:0-145378-66560, transaction was
>   waiting for: 123927 ms. 2013-12-10 14:48:28,055 INFO 
>   StorageManagerFactory - Rolling back storage transaction:
>   tcm:0-145378-66560 2013-12-10 14:48:28,058 DEBUG FSEntityManager -
>   Nothing to roll back for transaction tcm:0-145378-66560. 2013-12-10
>   14:48:28,064 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Cleaning up transaction
>   tcm:0-145378-66560. 2013-12-10 14:48:28,994 WARN  PreCommitPhase -
>   Failed to Prepare: tcm:0-145378-66560 error:
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed! 2013-12-10
>   14:48:29,000 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Rolling back storage
>   transaction: tcm:0-145378-66560 2013-12-10 14:48:29,005 INFO 
>   StorageManagerFactory - Transaction: tcm:0-145378-66560 was no longer
>   or active or already rolled back 2013-12-10 14:48:29,007 WARN 
>   DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase
>   failure message: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-145378-66560,
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!,
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed! for transaction:
>   tcm:0-145378-66560

The same item publishes fine to another target.  What could the issue be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to the system being out of disk space, not enough in the filesystem location where the Deployer is configured to write:

[image]

The problem was resolved after freeing up diskspace, then deleting the contents of the Deployer's incoming work folder.